# List Json in Angular

Tags: html, angularjs, json, typescript

Hi Guys i have a small problem I am trying to list all products i got in my cart. I retrieve the data with a JSON Array. My code is very simple but it works except the listing ;)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MoltinService } from '../moltin/moltin.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/observable';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cart',
  templateUrl: './cart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cart.component.css']
})
export class CartComponent implements OnInit {
  cart: any;

  constructor(private moltinService: MoltinService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.moltinService.Moltin.Cart().Items()
      .then(cart=> {
        this.cart = cart.data;
        console.log(cart);
    }); 
  }
}
```

an my HTML is even shorter

```
<div class="pageWrapper space">
  <ng-template ngFor let-p [ngForOf]="cart">
    {{ data.id }}
  </ng-template>
</div>
```

my JSON looks like this:
[image]

but i always get the error: Cannot read property "id" of undefined

Every help would be very nice. Thank you guys ;)

Comment: Im not to familiar with this but im missing something here   {{ data.id }} i expect something like data[0].id

Comment: @Grumpy already tried it but it returns: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: Maybe you can try debugging by having Angular display the JSON of the objects you're trying to access? Like {{ data | json }} and {{ cart | json }} -- just to see if those objects are in the view as expected.

Comment: @RoboBear Wow cool worked a little bit. The data was send to the console because it only can render strings but now i know cart is right thanks ;)

Comment: @Michael I'm not an expert in Angular but have you tried `{{ p.id }}`? because the `let-p` it's the variable you get when iterating over the cart object

Comment: @ZoT   wuhuuuu that fixed it thank you very much ;)

Answer (score 1):

@Zot is right, you are iterating and using p as the current value.

I recommend to use a different syntax, easier to understand:

```
<div class="pageWrapper space">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of cart">
    {{ item.id }}
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution came from @ZoT and i have to use `{{ p.id }`} because `let-p`defines p as variable when i iterate over the cart object.

```
<div class="pageWrapper space">
  <ng-template ngFor let-p [ngForOf]="cart">
    {{ p.id }}
  </ng-template>
</div>
```

Thank you guys ;)

Answer (score 0):

> *I recommend to use  this syntax it's work well for me:*

```
<div class="pageWrapper space">
  <ng-template *ngFor="let item of cart">
    {{ item.id }}
  </ng-template>
</div>
```